# C# Blazor - draggable using a variable not working

Tags: c#, html, drag-and-drop, blazor

My drag and drop functionality works with the following html section:

```
<div class="outer" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
   @foreach (CustomObject o in ObjectList)
   {
      <div draggable="true" @key="o.Rank" @ondrag="@(()=> StartDrag(o))" @ondrop="@(()=> Drop(o))" class="inner">
      ...
      </div>
   }
</div>
```

But I want to make "draggable" work with a variable so I can turn it on and off.

In my code section I add:

```
private bool isDraggable = true;
```

All of the following don't allow for the drag and drop functionality to work:

```
draggable="isDraggable"
draggable="@isDraggable"
draggable=isDraggable
draggable=@isDraggable
```

Is there something I am missing here? or can you just flat out not make draggable work with a variable??

Comment: Is `isDraggable` supposed to be a component parameter? If so, it needs to be public and have a `[Parameter]` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out:

```
draggable="@isDraggable.ToString()"
```

Comment: For the curious, this is because Blazor defines `attribute="@someBool"` to emit `attribute` when true and nothing when false -- it will never emit `attribute="true"`, which is what is needed for `draggable`.  It's great for most other HTML attributes such as `disabled` though, this one just has a weirder definition.